# Custom effect for entry. Clear text button

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.forms, effects, custom-renderer

I am creating a custom entry and have everything almost working correctly. On most of my entrys, the x button will show and hide when there is text or no text in the entry. However for some reason when I click on one of my entrys, it clears whatever is in it.

[image: Tapping anywhere in that box clears the entry]

Here is where I'm checking if my x is tapped:

```
public class OnDrawableTouchListener : Java.Lang.Object, Android.Views.View.IOnTouchListener
{
    public bool OnTouch(Android.Views.View v, MotionEvent e)
    {
        if (v is EditText && e.Action == MotionEventActions.Up)
        {
            EditText editText = (EditText)v;
            if (!editText.Text.Equals(""))
                editText.SetCompoundDrawablesRelativeWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0, Resource.Drawable.Subtraction20, 0);

            if (editText.GetCompoundDrawables()[2] != null)
            {
                //get actual position of tap
                if (e.RawX >= (editText.Right - editText.GetCompoundDrawables()[2].Bounds.Width()))
                {
                    //clear entry
                    editText.Text = string.Empty;
                    return true;
                }
            }
        }
        return false;
    }
}
```

[image: here's a picture of the x that clears the text]

Comment: What is your main issue?

Comment: When I click on that entry area where my arrow points, it clears my entry. It should only clear if I hit the x that pops up on the right.

Comment: I updated the post to show a picture of the x that clears the entry.